# Not able to find the downloaded file in Saucelabs

Tags: java, excel, selenium, csv, saucelabs

I am executing testscripts written in Selenium Java on SauceLabs.
Scenario is to launch the browser and download one csv file and read the file for count and add some records to the same.
But I am not able to find the path for the downloaded file.

Please help me in finding the file downloaded by script running on SauceLabs

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible to do the way you are thinking.

A few alternate options available: https://support.saucelabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005860628-Testing-PDF-Downloads

Answer (score 0):

> downloading files is not considered an important aspect of emulating
> user interaction with the web platform.
> [Selenium.dev](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/worst_practices/file_downloads/)

**When we are testing file download we care about a few tests:**

1. Does the Download button invoke a request on the correct link
2. Does the link contain the appropriate resource
3. Does the resource that you download contain the correct content.

**To test 1:**
Open browser, find your link, get the `href` and assert that it's correct

**To test 2:**
You do not need Sauce Labs or Selenium but can reuse the link from Test 1 and

> Find the link using Selenium, along with any required cookies, and
> pass it to an HTTP request library, such as REST Assured (Java), fetch
> (JavaScript), or libcurl (cross-platform).
> [10 testing scenarios you should never automate with Selenium](https://techbeacon.com/app-dev-testing/10-testing-scenarios-you-should-never-automate-selenium)

**Test test 3:**
You also don't need Selenium or Sauce and it's simply a continuation of Test 2. Once you download your resource using a simple web request, open your file and check it for valid content.

Comment: Have to disagree. Selenium is e2e tool in first place but steps you have described are more for integration testing. If I need to check that user can pass some e2e flow where the last step is downloading of pdf file then test should check that after the actual click file is downloaded. Everything could goes wrong, another element could get a click, script that should do the work in event listener might not be downloaded or be broken or .... . So when we talk about e2e test there is no way to check the action with sauce labs.